# How to increase max open file limits for NFS v4 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have researched for some solutions, especially the ones for system services like mysqld.

1. Setup `fs.file-max=1000000`
2. Setup following on /etc/security/limits.conf

```
root  -     nofile         65535
*     -     nofile         65535
```

3. Add `DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535` on /etc/systemd/system.conf and /etc/systemd/user.conf
4. Add systemd config for `nfs-kernel-server`

```
    $ sudo systemctl edit nfs-kernel-server
    # Add following
    [Service]
    LimitNOFILE=65535
```

After reboot, nginx and mysqld work well after change `3.` is applied.
However NFS's soft/hard open file limits are still on default value.

```
$ ps aux|grep nfs
root     26694  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S   18:55   0:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
root     26696  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [nfsd]                     
root     26697  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [nfsd]                     
root     26698  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [nfsd]

$ cat /proc/26696/limits |grep 'Max open files'                                             
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```